# Django oauth2 responds with invalid client after months with successful use

Tags: ios, django, oauth-2.0, django-oauth

For around 4-5 months I have been developing an IOS app with a django backend. For communication between both ends, I use django-oauth2-toolkit, which has worked fine. I created a clientID and clientSecret, which has until now worked (tokens are generated, and give users access to my servers resources).

All of a sudden, access is now not possible, and instead I receive "invalid_client" responses from django. I honestly have no idea what to do here, as I'm fairly new to django, especially oauth2-toolkit. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: @JihoonBaek, Actually yes! Somehow my database lost the data to the oauth2 ClientID and ClientSecret that was previously set up for the app. I just needed to recreate it.